# 2012 Nissan Armada not starting

Tags: starting, nissan, intermittent-problems, armada

Within the last couple of months my car will randomly not start. When I turn the key all of the electronics come on and it will click but wont start.

It usually happens when I shut it off run in somewhere for a few min and then try to start it again when I'm  leaving. Or if I park it on my driveway which has a bit of an incline. I've had my battery and alternator checked and both were good. I had a Nissan battery put in towards the end of last year.

The only way I have been able to get it to start when this happens is to turn the key very slow and it starts right up. Why would it be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like a problem with the ignition starter switch. It's the piece which attaches to the lock cylinder (the part the key goes into) and tells the vehicle to actually start the engine. From your description, this seems most likely. Below is the image of the part which goes into your Armada.

**NOTE:** I wouldn't just change out this part (not cheap) to see if it's the issue. I've not worked on any Nissans like yours before, so I don't know the ins/outs of what exactly is needed to replace this, such as if there's any programming which needs to happen with replacement. I also don't know how you'd test this to prove it is the problem.

[image]